# Usage of "face"

Tags: meaning

Both in transitive and intransitive form, "face" has a definition that describes a specified direction.

For example,

1. The window of Building A faces the window of Building B.
2. The window of Building A faces to the window of Building B.

If I'd like to describe the direction they face, is there any difference between the sentences described above?

Thank you!

Comment: The first example is by far the more common. Indeed I'm not sure that example two is strictly idiomatic - though only a pedant would object.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker... kind of confused about that.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  Cambridge Dictionary:
To face - 
to turn or be turned towards something physically; to be opposite something:

The balcony faced towards the sea.

Our apartment faces south.

Their houses face each other across the street.

So you can use the preposition, but it can be omitted as well.
I would use no preposition.